# Is the Jacobian different for different $l^p$ norms?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, jacobian

Because the Jacobian is related to the measure of an integral, and the measure is related to the norm/metric of the space, does the Jacobian behave differently for $l^p$ spaces where $p$ isn't $2$

[Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/454885/is-the-jacobian-different-for-different-cal-lp-norms/454888#454888)

Comment: What is the Jacobian?

Comment: The factor needed in front of the volume form when switching between coordinates: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant